# Find the height of prime ideal $p=(x_n-x_1^n,\ldots ,x_2-x_1^n)$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, prime-factorization

> Find $\operatorname{ht}(p)$  where $p=(x_n-x_1^n,\dots,x_2-x_1^n)$ ideal of  $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

$\operatorname{ht}(p)=$ height of a prime $p$

> How to prove $p$ is prime ?

Comment: I don't think that this question should be closed (it has 1 close vote), because it has a single, accepted answer which just gives a **hint**. So I see no reason why this question should be closed.

Comment: (Also, @user161991, if you found the given answer helpful then you should upvote it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use repeatedly $R[X]/(X-a)\simeq R$ ($a\in R$) and show that $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/p\simeq\mathbb C[x_1]$, so $p$ is prime of height $n-1$.